# odd error with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx,tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1cm and 1.5cm]
    \node[]at (0,0) (e1){$G_0$};
    \node[]at(1.75,-1.75) (aux1){};
    \shade[ball color=red] at (1.0,1.0) circle(0.2) {scat1};
    \draw[path] (e1) -- (aux1);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

is giving error:

```
! Use of \@next doesn't match its definition.
\beamer@doifinframe ... \shade [ball color=red] at
                                                   (1.0,1.0) circle(0.2) {sc...
l.11 \end{frame}
```

everything is fine, if i remove `at ()` from shade, only its in wrong position

Comment: Can you also share the "everything is fine" version?

Comment: Offtopic: you don't need "\usepackage{graphicx}" with beamer

Comment: @samcarter: just remove at () part, and sphere is coming at e1.

Comment: As the answer shows, you're not supposed to use the `at` keyword in this context. `at` only applies to nodes, while `\shade` is similar to `\fill`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code worked without the `at`, but with the `(1.0,1.0)` also needed to replace the `\draw[path]` by `\path[draw]` and remove the `{scat1}`.

Working code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1cm and 1.5cm]
    \node at(0,0) (e1){$G_0$};
    \node at(1.75,-1.75) (aux1){};
    \shade[ball color=red] (1.0,1.0) circle(0.2);
    \path[draw] (e1) -- (aux1);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

off-topic: `graphicx` is loaded with tikz too